cos function strange question in numerical analysis
enter image description here
I have a numerical analysis question that I am trying to solve as follows.
The steps I did to solve this question are as follows;
first I calculated cos(0.5) and found the result 1. T=1
and I go and as step 1;
1-(0.5^2 / 2!) = 0.875
I then calculated the relative error percentage as follows;
€a = [T1 - T0 / T1] x 100 = 14.29% relative error result
As step 2;
1-(0.5^2/2!) + (0.5^4/4!) = 0.875 + 0.002604 = 0.87760
I then calculated the relative error percentage as follows;
€a = [T2 - T1 / T2] x 100 = 0,30% relative error result
Step 3;
1-(0.5^2/2!) + (0.5^4/4!) - (0.5^6/6!) = -1.292396
and I'm stuck here and I don't know what to do next because the next values I find are even higher than the previous error values.
Can you help me where I am making the mistake. I am already grateful to the community.
(by the way I tried to add mathematical expressions in latex format and failed sorry)

Is there anyone who can help with this issue?

I see two errors or points of misunderstanding.

The series is for arguments in radians, that is, in the scale for the angle where the full turn has angle $2\pi$. Roughly $0.5\approx \frac\pi6$ and $\cos(\frac\pi6)=\frac{\sqrt3}2\approx\frac56=0.83..$. Thus switch your calculator from degree to radians.

In step 3 some mistyping must have happened. The additional term is very small, so should not give such a relatively large change.



what you mean is that I should take cos(0.5) in radians. And I get a value like cos(0.5) = 0.877.... Did I understand you correctly? @Lutz Lehmann

Yes, $0.877582561890372716116...$ Which is what the first two values moved towards.

then what should I do?
Isn't it to take the value cos(0.5) = 0.877 and apply the next steps?
So I am asking to understand
My 1 step is as follows;
cos(0.5) = 0.877
cos(0.5) = 1 - (0.5^2 / 2!) = 0.875
€a = | (0.875 - 0.877) / 0.875 | x 100 = 0.2285
That's what I understand from the corrections we've made. Are my steps correct? @Lutz Lehmann

You have a very accurate value from some external source. Your task begins with comparing that with the less accurate approximations by the values of the partial sum of the cosine power series. For the relative error you usually take the more accurate value for the denominator.

but if this is true, since there are more than 2 significant values, we have reached the correct value in one iteration? @Lutz Lehmann

Yes. But the task asks to find error bounds that do not use the exact value. Look up the Leibniz test and related error bounds. To challenge your findings, try to find the number of terms for 10 and 20 decimals before evaluating the partial sums.
